# window is not defined in server side render window.webpackJsonp

Tags: webpack, webpacker, react-on-rails

I'm attempting to upgrade a Rails/Webpacker/ReactOnRails application to webpack 4. I have included a call to `environment.splitChunks`. That is placing this code:

```
window.webpackJsonp=window.webpackJsonp||[]).push([[11],.......
```

in my bundle. Since this is my server side bundle, `window` does not exist. Is there a way to completely exclude this bundle from having webpackJsonp added?

I have tried these two configurations:

```
environment.splitChunks();
```

and

```
environment.splitChunks(config =>
  Object.assign({}, config, {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        chunks(chunk) {
          return chunk.name !== 'server-bundle';
        }
      }
    }
  })
);
```

Both end up with the same result. If I don't include `splitChunks`, my code works fine.

I also just tried:

```
environment.splitChunks(config =>
  Object.assign({}, config, {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          server: {
            test: /server-bundle/,
            minChunks: 99999 // Do not ever chunk this file
          }
        }
      }
    }
  })
);
```

and

```
environment.splitChunks(config =>
  Object.assign({}, config, {
    optimization: {
      splitChunks: {
        cacheGroups: {
          server: {
            test: /server-bundle/,
            minChunks: 99999 // Do not ever chunk this file
          }
        },
        chunks(chunk) {
          return chunk.name !== 'server-bundle';
        }
      }
    }
  })
);
```

I thought one of those would put it in its own group that didn't get chunked, but no dice.

Comment: How’d you end up resolving this?

Comment: I went back to webpack 3 unfortunately